# What's at my back?

Tags: word, wordplay

I always have something on my back whenever I use my PC and I have some definitons to figure out what it is.

1. financial institution that accepts deposits from the public
2. a family of large marine crustaceans
3. used for millennia to shape, split and cut wood
4. slender width
5. a type of pot specialized for boiling water
6. between the upper and lower parts of the arm
7. aromatic beverage native to East Asia

Can you guess what is at my back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is a

> Blanket

Answers

> 1. Bank
>  2. Lobster
>  3. Axe
>  4. Narrow
>  5. Kettle
>  6. Elbow
>  7. Tea

Then

> taking the first letters gives a BLANKET, whis is at your back because you may be cold.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not cold. Just more relaxed with it.